# how to avoid duplication with 2D Sum

Tags: summation, data

I would like to do 2D $\sum_{i,j}$ where $i\neq j$ and only $(i,j)$ must included and avoiding $(j,i)$ due to symmetry. Here as an example:

```
Sum[If[i == j, 0, F[i] Y[j]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]

 
F[2] Y[1] + F[3] Y[1] + F[1] Y[2] + F[3] Y[2] + F[1] Y[3] + F[2] Y[3]
```

to divide duplication I need to divide this by factor 2 to avoid repeated points. For large data, this is time-consuming, I would like the output to be

```
 F[2] Y[1] + F[3] Y[1] + F[3] Y[2]
```

Comment: `Sum[If[i == j, 0, F[i] Y[j]], {i, 3}, {j, 1, i}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Sum[If[i == j, 0, F[i] Y[j]], {i, 3}, {j, i, 3}]
```

> ```
> F[1] Y[2] + F[1] Y[3] + F[2] Y[3]
> ```

and

```
Sum[If[i <= j, 0, F[i] Y[j]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
```

> ```
> F[2] Y[1] + F[3] Y[1] + F[3] Y[2]
> ```

Comment: Or more simply since `i != j` start `j` at `i+1`, i.e., `Sum[F[i] Y[j], {i, 3}, {j, i + 1, 3}]`

Comment: Sum[Boole[i != j] F[i] Y[j], {i, 3}, {j, i}]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Boole`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) like so:

```
Sum[Boole[i != j] F[i] Y[j], {i, 3}, {j, i}]
```

> `Sum[Boole[i != j] F[i] Y[j], {i, 3}, {j, i}]`

Comment: Although this gives the correct result, this will still calculate `F` and `Y` when `i == j`. If `F` and/or `Y` are computationally expensive, this is inefficient. Same applies to comment by @demm

Comment: @BobHanlon Missed the previous comment. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Never thought about that, and this is my go-to approach for my projects. I will reconsider henceforth. Many thanks :)